# print bi and trigrams of each word in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, combinatorics

I need to print all the possible bi and trigrams for each word in array tempsArray that is being converted from fwords.txt. Here is the code i have copied and pasted together.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Ngram {

public static List<String> ngrams(int n, String str) {
    List<String> ngrams = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length - n + 1; i++)
        ngrams.add(concat(words, i, i+n));
    return ngrams;
}

public static String concat(String[] words, int start, int end) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        sb.append((i > start ? " " : "") + words[i]);
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String token1 = "";
// create Scanner inFile1
Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("fwords.txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");
 List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();
// while loop
while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
  // find next line
  token1 = inFile1.next();
  temps.add(token1);
}
inFile1.close();
String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);




    for (int n = 1; n <= 3; n++) {
        for (String ngram : ngrams(n, tempsArray[1] ))
            System.out.println(ngram);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

for (String ngram : ngrams(n, tempsArray[1] )) will print the bi and trigrams for the second word in the array. how can i do this for each word in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over all words in the array, use two loops.  The outermost will loop over each element of `tempsArray`.  The rest comes from your code (except number `1` is replaced with index `j`).

```
for (int j =0 j < tempsArray.length; j ++ ) { 
  for (int n = 1; n <= 3; n++) {
    for (String ngram : ngrams(n, tempsArray[j] ))
      System.out.println(ngram);
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

or

```
for (String t: tempsArray ) { 
  for (int n = 1; n <= 3; n++) {
    for (String ngram : ngrams(n, t))
      System.out.println(ngram);
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```